# Is Firebase Cloud Messaging considered a message broker?

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, distributed-computing, messagebroker

I have a task to implement a message broker at choice in a distributed system. Is Firebase Cloud Messaging considered one?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No. At the very least not identical in a sense, however both are related to interchanging of messages.

[Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging) is a messaging service commonly (if not always) used for [Push Notifications](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_Notification):

> A **push notification** is a message that is "pushed" from backend server or application to user interface, e.g. (But not limited to) mobile applications and desktop applications. It is more user experience specific which is different from [Push technology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology), which pushes the requests between components such as server to server communication. A common scenario of push notification is the client application pops up a message in front of application's user information, along with the alert sounds. The notification could also coupled with images and hyper text link in some cases. Via interacting with the push notification it usually brings up the client applications to the front.

The service could be described as a *middleware* that handles the sending/delivery of the message between the App Server (usually the sender) and the client (the receiver). But for them to communicate accordingly, both the Sender and Receiver must be configured to receive the message itself (i.e. they are the ones that have to adjust to the message).

While a [Message Broker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_broker) is described as:

> In [computer programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_programming), a **message broker** is an intermediary [program module](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_programming) that translates a message from the formal messaging protocol of the sender to the formal messaging protocol of the receiver. Message brokers are elements in telecommunication or computer networks where software applications communicate by exchanging formally-defined messages. Message brokers are a building block of [Message oriented middleware](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_oriented_middleware).

From the description itself, the message broker could also be considered as a *middleware*, but it's task is more on transforming/translating/adjusting the message so that it is would be *smoothly* received by the receiver.

There is also an available list of Message Broker softwares from the Wikipedia page, containing:

> - [Apache ActiveMQ](https://activemq.apache.org)
> - [Apache Kafka](https://kafka.apache.org)
> - [Apache Qpid](https://qpid.apache.org)
> - [Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org)
> - [Cloverleaf (E-Novation Lifeline)](https://www.enovationgroup.com/en/cloverleaf)
> - Comverse Message Broker ([Comverse Technology](http://cmvt.com/))
> - [Enduro/X Transactional Message Queue (TMQ)](https://github.com/endurox-dev/endurox)
> - Financial Fusion Message Broker (Sybase - [acquired](https://techcrunch.com/2010/05/12/confirmed-sap-to-acquire-sybase-for-5-8-billion) by [SAP](https://www.sap.com/index.html) in 2010)
> - [JBoss A-MQ](https://developers.redhat.com/products/amq/overview) (aka. Fuse Message Broker - enterprise ActiveMQ - [acquired](https://www.redhat.com/en/about/press-releases/red-hat-to-acquire-fusesource) by [RedHat](https://www.redhat.com) in 2012)
> - [Gearman](http://gearman.org)
> - [HornetQ (Red Hat)](https://hornetq.jboss.org) ([donated](http://hornetq.blogspot.com/2015/06/hornetq-apache-donation-and-apache.html) to Apache ActiveMQ community)
> - [IBM Integration Bus](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSMKHH/mapfiles/product_welcome.html)
> - [IBM Message Queues](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ/com.ibm.mq.helphome.doc/product_welcome_wmq.htm)
> - [JBoss Messaging](https://jbossmessaging.jboss.org) (JBoss - moved to HornetQ and now it's in bug-fix mode)
> - [JORAM](https://joram.ow2.io)
> - [Azure Service Bus (Microsoft)](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/service-bus)
> - [BizTalk Server (Microsoft)](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/cloud-platform/biztalk)
> - [NATS (MIT Open Source License, written in Go)](https://nats.io)
> - [Open Message Queue](https://javaee.github.io/openmq)
> - [Oracle Message Broker (Oracle Corporation)](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A87860_01/doc/ois.817/a83729/adois08.htm)
> - [QDB (Apache License 2.0, supports message replay by timestamp)](http://qdb.io)
> - [RabbitMQ (Mozilla Public License, written in Erlang)](https://www.rabbitmq.com)
> - [Redis](https://redis.io) An open source, in-memory data structure store, used as a database, cache and message broker.
> - [SAP PI (SAP AG)](https://blogs.sap.com/2013/05/21/sap-pi-for-beginners)
> - [Solace Systems Message Router](https://solace.com/products/tech/#multi-service)
> - [Spread Toolkit](http://www.spread.org/apps.html)
> - [Tarantool, a NoSQL database, with a set of stored procedures for message queues](https://www.tarantool.io/en/developers)
> - [WSO2 Message Broker](https://wso2.com/products/message-broker)

Comment: Great answer. Are there any Message broker specific features that can not be achived with firebase cloud messaging?

Comment: Thanks Alexandru. The FCM service is *totally different* when compared to a message broker. Depending on the message you need to *transform*, your implementation would probably be vast and I don't see how FCM could be used for it.

Comment: FCM does not appear to be able to deliver to 1 of N subscribers as is common with a message queue. Delivery to 1 of a group of consumers is used for dynamic load balancing of consumers in a consumer group.